# Why can't i just calculate the screen dimensions and by that resize the image?

Tags: android, image-resizing, image-scaling

I found a lot questions and answers of people asking how to adjust the image to fit the device screen and i thought to myself- if i can get the device resolution, using

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

why can't i just scale/resize the image by lets say 1/5 of the screen?
Thats way i can do lets say 1/5 of space 2/5 of image and another 1/5 of text and its supposed  to fit all the device's, Am i missing something here?

also why do i get a "deprecated" warning in this code?

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance for the help

Comment: If you want to size a UI element by percentage of screen, then use the `android:layout_weight` attribute in the layout XML file. I'm guessing you meant to put "3/5 of image" (not 2/5) so... three elements with weights of 1:3:1 will be sized to the corresponding sum of all weights. So in this case 1+3+1=5. The result is the first will fill 1/5, the second 3/5 and the third 1/5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why can't i just scale/resize the image by lets say 1/5 of the screen?

You can, and if you want to have your image take up some relative amount of the screen size, then this and using a `LinearLayout` with weights (as pointed out by others) are probably your only options. Do note that you probably don't want to do any image scaling on the main UI thread and that you should try doing it as efficiently as possible. Have a look at [the guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for some good practices.

Also note that the screen width (and especially the screen height) isn't necessarily the amount of space available for your image and/or UI. There may be margins/padding enforced, or other components present; for instance the ActionBar.

> also why do i get a "deprecated" warning in this code?

See the documentation for either [`Display.getHeight()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getHeight%28%29) or [`Display.getWidth()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getWidth%28%29):

> *This method was deprecated in API level 13. Use [`getSize(Point)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) instead.*

Basically Google has told developers it may stop supporting the aforementioned methods in future platform versions. Hence, you should migrate away from them when possible. Most developers will end up writing their own helper method that uses the deprecated approach on older platforms (pre API level 13 in this case) and `getSize(...)` on newer platforms. You can use the [`Build.VERSION_CODES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In Android your application may not cover entire screen. Even if you disable titlebar/statusbar etc you can still have device-specific chrome (like on screen button in Android 3.0).

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, but still - leaving extra spaces in all sides of the screen seems to me a way better solution than just fitting it in small-medium-large folders..

Comment: You can use LinearLayout with weights 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2 to fit your elements. Or you can calculate it manually but you must use View dimensions, not Device. And remember to update layout when configuration change (for example orientation change)